# unreal engine how to check if something has been done within a time limit

Tags: animation, game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm looking to set up an animation in which the character does a certain thing if the player hasn't moved within a few seconds. I was thinking something to do with checking with the event tick but that would probably a very inefficient way to do so, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Checking on the tick event in an abp or the native animation instance is probably the most correct thing to do. You might already be reading the player's velocity there anyway if you're looking to blend between a walk/run cycle for example. Ticking itself is expensive but there are cases where it's unavoidable and the anim blueprint is generally one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the delay node.

After an event that triggers once your character stops moving, use the delay node and set it to a couple of seconds. Then, after this node start the animation.